# How can I validate for whitespaces in textbox

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input, project

I am validating a text box using javascript, now what happens is that if the text box = '' or in other words is empty, then a message appears stating "Please Enter in a Room Number", if not then display an empty string "".

Now this is fine if the text box is empty but if I type in a space or enter for example and then submit the form, then the validation message does not appear in this instance.

How is it supposed to be coded so that if a textbox is empty of contains whitespaces, then it should display a message?

Below is my code:

```
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Create a Session</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

     function validation() {
    var roomTextO = document.getElementById("room");
    var errRoomMsgO = document.getElementById("roomAlert");

    if (roomTextO.value == ""){
                    errRoomMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Enter in a Room Number";
                }else{
                    errRoomMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
                }  

            }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form action="create_session.php" method="post" name="sessionform">

    <p><strong>8: Room:</strong> <input type="text" id="room">
<br/><span id="roomAlert"></span></p>      <!-- Enter Room here-->

    </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: i think you should also validates for only numbers

Comment: A room number actually consist of letters as well: e.g CW1/05

Comment: in this case you should trim the values or see the answers below. read more http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim the contents of the textbox first:

```
roomTextO.trim().value
```

Comment: While your suggestion is valid, `trim()` is not a native JavaScript function! Check this blog post http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/f1031.shtml or Google for some options.

Comment: That did not work. Did u mean put it like this: roomTextO.trim().value == "" in my if function instead of roomTextO.value == "".

Comment: Interesting, I was under the impression that it was a native function. Thanks for the correction. And yes, I meant to replace roomTextO.value with roomTextO.trim().value

Comment: Sorry got it completely wrong, this is the better answer. Thank you

Comment: function trim(str){
 return str.replace(/(?:(?:^|\n)\s+|\s+(?:$|\n))/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}